# Filtering nested lists of Tuples in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, filter, tuples

I have something like this in python `[[(1,2),(3,7)],[(5,22)],[(4,-1),(-3,34),(41,2)]]` and I want to filter the sub lists with "filter" So the condition will be if the sum of all the first element of each tuple in the sub list be greater than 5 and if not delete the sub list.

Maybe you have any idea how can do it ? (without packages or imports)
Thanks

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Comment: Please always show your code/effort first, before asking people to help... It's more convincing than just `throw` out a question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested list comprehension with a filter condition like this:

```
sub_lists = [[(1,2),(3,7)],[(5,22)],[(4,-1),(-3,34),(41,2)]]

filtered_sub_lists = [
    sub_list for sub_list in sub_lists if sum(values[0] for values in sub_list) > 5
]

print(filtered_sub_lists)
>>> [[(4, -1), (-3, 34), (41, 2)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use list comprehension

```
a = [[(1,2),(3,7)],[(5,22)],[(4,-1),(-3,34),(41,2)]]
b = [x for x in a if sum(y for y,_ in x) > 5]
```

Edited based on comment from azro.

x is each sub array in a,  and the sum takes the first element of each sub array and if the total is greater than 5 then x is included in b.

Comment: More performant to use the generator syntax `sum(y for y, _ in x)`, that doesn't create an intermediate list ;)